# program who returns true or false whether a matrix is a magic square or not

Tags: python, matrix, boolean

I'm trying to make a program that returns a boolean whether a matrix is a magic square or not. I try to submit this code at my college's website, but it returns "Wrong Answer". I can't see what's wrong with it. Can you help me?

```
def magico(xs):

    #print(soma(xs),soma2(xs),diag(xs))
    if(soma(xs) == soma2(xs) == diag(xs) != -1 ):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def soma(xs):

    sant = 0
    s = 0
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        if(s != sant):
            return -1
        s = 0
        for j in range(len(xs)):
            s = s + int(xs[i][j])
        sant = s
    return s

def soma2(xs):

    s = 0
    sant = 0
    for j in range(len(xs)):
        if(s != sant):
            return -1
        s = 0
        for i in range(len(xs)):
            s = s + int(xs[j][i])
        sant = s
    return s

def diag(xs):

    s = 0
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        s = s + int(xs[i][i])
    t = 0
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        t = t + int(xs[i][len(xs) - 1 - i])
    if(s == t):
        return s
    else:
        return -1
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is a magic square, in your own words please.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode

```
magic = true
answer = sum(square)/n_rows(square)
for r in rows(square):
    if sum(r) not equal to answer
        magic = false
for c in columns(square):
    if sum(c) not equal to answer
        magic = false
d1 = principal_diagonal(square)
d2 = secondary_diagonal(square)
if sum(d1) or sum(d2) not equal to answer
    magic = false

display magic
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if the matrix is square, you are not checking if the numbers in the matrix are unique.  Beyond that you have a serious coding issue:
Your loops all end with

```
sant = s
```

They start with

```
if(s != sant):
```

But you have just made them equal...